# Не срабатывает callback с первого раза в aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram, callback

Пишу бота на aiogram, возникла проблема с callback
Когда я нажимаю на кнопку Принять(у этой кнопки callback - accept), то заявка должна была измениться, но она не изменяется, а на кнопке идет загрузка, будто что то мешает калбэку отправится
версия aiogram 2.25.1

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data in ['accept'], state=Form.confirmation)
async def accept_callback(callback: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    current_date = datetime.now()
    data = await state.get_data()
    amount_virt = data['amount_virt']
    nickname = data['nickname']
    server = data['server']
    project = data['project']
    username = callback.from_user.username
    message_id = callback.message.message_id
    Request.update(status=f'Была принята админом - @{username}').where(Request.status == 'НЕ ПРИНЯТА').execute()
    await bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=admins_chat, message_id=message_id,text=f' Новая заявка на покупку виртов! \n ДАТА: {current_date} \n️ ПРОЕКТ: {project} ️\n СЕРВЕР: {server} \n КОЛИЧЕСТВО: {amount_virt} \n НИК: {nickname} \n ЮЗЕРНЕЙМ ДЛЯ СВЯЗИ: @{username} \n СТАТУС ЗАЯВКИ: Принял - @{username} ',parse_mode='MARKDOWN')
    await state.finish()
    await callback.answer()
    
@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data in ['notaccept'], state=Form.confirmation)
async def notaccept_callback(callback: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    await callback.message.answer('Введите причину отмены заявки')
    await state.update_data(callback_query=callback)
    await Form.reason.set()

@dp.message_handler(lambda message: message.text, state=Form.reason)
async def notaccept(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    current_date = datetime.now()
    data = await state.get_data()
    reason = message.text
    callback_query = data['callback_query']
    amount_virt = data['amount_virt']
    nickname = data['nickname']
    server = data['server']
    project = data['project']
    username = callback_query.from_user.username
    chat_id = callback_query.message.chat.id
    message_id = callback_query.message.message_id
    Request.update(
        status=f'Была отклонена админом - @{username}',
        reason=f'Причина - {reason}'
    ).where(
        (Request.status == 'НЕ ПРИНЯТА') & (Request.reason == '-')
    ).execute()
    await bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=chat_id,message_id=message_id,text=f' Новая заявка на покупку виртов! \n ДАТА: {current_date} \n️ ПРОЕКТ: {project} ️\n СЕРВЕР: {server} \n КОЛИЧЕСТВО: {amount_virt} \n НИК: {nickname} \n ЮЗЕРНЕЙМ ДЛЯ СВЯЗИ: @{username} \n СТАТУС ЗАЯВКИ: Отклонил - @{username}, причина - {reason} ',parse_mode='MARKDOWN')
    await state.finish()
```

если я правильно понял
то этот пример должен работать

```
import string
from datetime import datetime
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from aiogram.contrib.middlewares.logging import LoggingMiddleware
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters import Command, Text
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import State, StatesGroup
from aiogram.types import ParseMode, ReplyKeyboardRemove, InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup
import random
from aaio.exceptions.aaio_bad_request import AAIOBadRequest
import asyncio
import math
import pydantic
from data_base import *
from peewee import DoesNotExist
import logging
from aaio import AAIO
import requests

API_TOKEN = 'апи'
bot = Bot(token=API_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=MemoryStorage())
dp.middleware.setup(LoggingMiddleware())

class Form(StatesGroup):
    project = State()
    nickname = State()
    server = State()
    confirmation = State()
    amount = State()
    reason = State()
    referral_code = State()
    amount = State()

@dp.message_handler(Command('start'))
async def welcome(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    kb = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=3)
    cmd_buy = types.KeyboardButton(text=' Купить вирты ')
    kb.add(cmd_buy)
    await message.answer('текст', reply_markup=kb, parse_mode="HTML")

@dp.message_handler(lambda message: message.text == ' Купить вирты ')
async def select_project(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    kb_project = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=2)
    cmd_arizona = types.KeyboardButton(text='Arizona RP')
    cmd_gta5rp = types.KeyboardButton(text='GTA5 RP')
    cmd_back = types.KeyboardButton(text='Назад')
    kb_project.add(cmd_arizona, cmd_gta5rp, cmd_back)
    await Form.project.set()

@dp.message_handler(lambda message: message.text in ['Arizona RP', 'GTA5 RP'], state=Form.project)
async def input_nick(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    project = message.text
    await state.update_data(project=project)
    await message.answer('Введите ваш ник в формате: Имя_Фамилия', reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardRemove())
    await Form.nickname.set()

@dp.message_handler(lambda message: message.text != 'Назад', state=Form.nickname)
async def input_server(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    nickname = message.text
    await state.update_data(nickname=nickname)
    await message.answer('Введите сервер')
    await Form.server.set()

@dp.message_handler(lambda message: message.text != 'Назад', state=Form.server)
async def input_amount(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    server = message.text
    await state.update_data(server=server)
    await message.answer('Введите количество покупаемой валюты')
    await Form.amount.set()

@dp.message_handler(lambda message: message.text != 'Назад', state=Form.amount)
async def yes_no(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    amount_virt = message.text
    await state.update_data(amount_virt=amount_virt)
    kb_yes_no = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=2)
    cmd_yes = types.KeyboardButton(text='Да')
    cmd_no = types.KeyboardButton(text='Нет')
    kb_yes_no.add(cmd_yes, cmd_no)
    data = await state.get_data()
    project = data['project']
    server = data['server']
    nickname = data['nickname']
    await message.answer(f'Нажмите на кнопку "Да"', reply_markup=kb_yes_no)
    await Form.confirmation.set()

@dp.message_handler(lambda message: message.text == 'Да', state=Form.confirmation)
async def accept_application(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    current_date = datetime.now()
    data = await state.get_data()
    amount_virt = data['amount_virt']
    nickname = data['nickname']
    server = data['server']
    project = data['project']
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    username = message.from_user.username
    button1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Принять', callback_data='accept')
    button2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Отклонить', callback_data='notaccept')
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup().add(button1, button2)
    await message.answer('Вы подтвердили данные\nОтправлена заявка на покупку виртуальной валюты администраторам\nС вами скоро свяжутся\n*Спасибо что доверяете нам!*', parse_mode='MARKDOWN', reply_markup=kb)
    await bot.send_message(chat_id, f'Новая заявка на покупку виртов!\n*ДАТА: {current_date}*\n*️ПРОЕКТ: {project}️*\n*СЕРВЕР: {server}*\n*КОЛИЧЕСТВО: {amount_virt}*\n*НИК: {nickname}*\n*ЮЗЕРНЕЙМ ДЛЯ СВЯЗИ: @{username}*\n*СТАТУС ЗАЯВКИ: НЕ ПРИНЯТА*', parse_mode='MARKDOWN', reply_markup=keyboard)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from aiogram import executor
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Comment: Можете пожалуйста привести минимально воспроизводимый пример формы, с которой происходит нажатие и отправка каллбэка?

Comment: Можете пожалуйста простым языков объяснить что надо

Comment: Простым языком, объясните что у вас в `Form` лежит и его реализация

Comment: `class Form(StatesGroup):
    project = State()
    nickname = State()
    server = State()
    confirmation = State()
    amount = State()
    reason = State()
    referral_code = State()
    amount = State()
`

Comment: Используйте кнопку "править" под вопросом

Comment: Только так получилось вставить Form
больше никак

Comment: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148824/discussion-between-fesol-and-acinit).